# Функция, удаляющая повторяющиеся элементы массива

Tags: c++

Написал код, который удаляет повторяющиеся элементы массива (но удаляет их копии, то есть если в массиве встретить два элемента: 2 2, то одну двойку он должен удалить, а вторую оставить).

Как можно теперь записать данный алгоритм в виде отдельной функции по удалению повторяющихся элементов массива?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
 
int main()
{
    srand((int)time(0));
    int n;
    cout <<"n="; cin >>n;
 
    double*a = new double[n];
 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
      a[i]=rand()%5 + 1;
      cout <<a[i]<<" ";
      }
    cout <<endl;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) 
    if (a[i]==a[j]) 
        { 
        for (int k = j; k < n; k++) 
        a[k]=a[k + 1]; 
        n--;
        j--;
        } 
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      cout <<a[i]<<" ";
      cout <<endl;
    delete[]a;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Объявить эту отдельную функцию, например, так: `void RemoveDuplicates(double* a, int n);`. В её тело поместить основной цикл (который удаляет повторяющиеся элементы). Вместо цикла в теле `main()` поместить вызов этой функции: `RemoveDuplicates(a,n);`

Comment: почему-то при выводе удалённые элементы не уничтожаются, а заполняются мусором. как это исправить?

Comment: @LShadow77, параметр `n` лучше сделать ссылкой, так как количество элементов изменится.

Comment: Требуется ли устойчивость алгоритма, т.е. чтобы все остающиеся элементы находились в том же относительном порядке, что и изначально? Например, для `1 3 5 2 4 6 2 2 3 3 6 6` надо получить строго `1 3 5 2 4 6`, или `1 2 3 4 5 6` тоже годится?

Comment: @maestro ну да, верно. Ну или можно вернуть новое значение `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Посоветовал бы воспользоваться `std::vector` и реализованными методами для решения этой задачи.

Но с вашим кодом функции будут выглядеть следующим образом:

```
template<typename T>
void resize(T* t,const int n)
{
    T* resize_arr = new T[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        resize_arr[i] = t[i];
    t = resize_arr;
    delete[] resize_arr;
}

template<typename T>
int reduce_duplicates(T& t, const int n)
{
    int res = n;
    for (int i = 0; i < res - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < res; j++)
        {
            if (t[i]==t[j])
            {
                for (int k = j; k < res; k++)
                {
                    t[k]=t[k + 1];
                    res--;
                    j--;
                    resize(&t, res);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: в данной задаче вектор к сожалению использовать нельзя(

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку о необходимости устойчивости ничего не сказано и раз у вас

```
double*a = new double[n];
```

(хотя сравнивать на равенство числа с плавающей точкой несколько, гм... опрометчиво)

то можно

```
sort(a,a+n);
n = unique(a,a+n) - a;
```

Все, у вас массив уникальных элементов из `n`штук...

См. https://ideone.com/P9f9fx

Comment: сортировку здесь использовать не нужно)

Comment: Без нее асимптотика будет O(n^2) (а с ней - O(n log n)), да и стандартный `unique` работать не будет. Это если вы утверждаете именно "не нужно", а не "не разрешено".